# SSRS Click event, store column value to a variable

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I need to store the value of the column from SSRS table, and display this value as a message.

Is it possible to store this value, when user clicks on a certain item?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve here?  Writing a new application to receive the parameter value as a URL?  Something else?

Comment: No, It's not possible.